# Macbook had logic board replaced twice, should I remove the old ones from my iCloud account?

Tags: icloud

My MacBook Pro 16 had the logic board replaced by apple twice as part of the warranty, so now in the Apple ID settings I see the new Mac,my iPhone, and two other Macs with the same serial number (the two old logic boards basicly), should I remove them or it doesn't matter ? Kinda paranoid with someone having access to my data.

PS : Find my was deactivated before the Logic board could be replaced on both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no downside to removing them - so if only for aesthetic purposes I would recommend it.

That being said, there's also little chance of any problem arising from leaving them on your account. If the board was replaced, it doesn't work anymore - and the authorization likely relies on the contents of the hard drive to be useful.